# Toggle/add/remove class in Jquery not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In my code i have two boxes, i want when i click on the box it should gain some width and when i click on another box it should gain the width and remove the extra width from previous box. I have done this successfully but when i click the extra width box again it does not removing it's extra width.

```js
$('.dos').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
});

$('.dos').click(function() {
  $('.dos').removeClass('clicked');
  $(this).addClass('clicked');
});
```

```css
#box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  transition: width 1s;
}

#box.clicked {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box" class="dos"></div>
<div id="box" class="dos"></div>
```

Just want toggle class should also work with `addClass` and `removeClass`

([Demo on jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/J3FTN/848/))

Comment: create a demo using `<>` so So people dont need to check the external link

Comment: Ids have to be **unique**

Comment: i'll remember it next time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J3FTN/850/) and try

```
$(this).toggleClass('clicked').siblings().removeClass('clicked');
```

**Demo**

```js
$('.dos').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('clicked').siblings().removeClass('clicked');    
});
```

```css
#box {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc; 
    transition: width 1s;
}

#box.clicked {
    width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box" class="dos"></div>
<div id="box" class="dos"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to play with adding/removing classes. Here is the [new fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J3FTN/851/)
Edit your **jQuery** code with this, I have just added a boolean variable:

```
var toggle = false;
$('.dos').click(function() { 
toggle = !toggle;
if (toggle) {
    $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
}

});
$('.dos').click(function() {
toggle = !toggle;
if (toggle) {
   $('.dos').removeClass('clicked');
    $(this).addClass('clicked');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are removing the class from the clicked button as well, if you want to achieve it you'll need to ignore the one clicked while removing the class

```
$('.dos').click(function() {
   $('.dos').not(this).removeClass('clicked');
   $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution is as below:

You was trying to toggle already toggled div. Plus always use unique ids in your code :)

```
$('.dos').click(function() {

  var out = this;
   $( ".dos" ).each(function( index ,element ) {
    console.log(element);
    if($(element).attr("id") != $(out).attr("id")){

         $(this).removeClass('clicked');
    }


    });

    $(this).toggleClass('clicked');

});
```